# Add an item at the end of tableview as a scrollable item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement a page as follows.

There is either a custom table view or collection view used to list repetitive items (such as number of orders, name of the order and price, etc..), but subtotal and taxes should also be part of the scrollable items. I wonder how making these items scrollable can be implemented. Promo code and add tip should not be scrollable items.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an item to the end of the tableView, you can create a custom view as per your need and add it as the footer view of the tableView.
For example:

```
 let footerView  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height:YOUR_VIEW_HEIGHT))
```

You can create as complex of a view hierarchy as you want.
Now add this footerView:

```
 yourTableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Comment: How about adding another cell?

Comment: If you want to display your total and taxes at the end of tableView , adding footer view will ensure they will appear at the end of tableView. Though you can go with adding another cell but with this approach you must have to ensure this cell will appear in the last.

Comment: @hotspring You can add a new cell with some conditions but putting some extra condition effects on the performance and make your code little bit complicate then taking footerView. This appoarch is perfect.Up-votable.